# What is the equivalent to multiple autofac .As<T>() in DryIoc?

Tags: dryioc

In switching over from Autofac to DryIoc, I have a need to implement something akin to `.As<IService1>().As<IService2>()`.

Given the following class

```cs
public interface IService1
{
    void DoStuff {}
}
public interface IService2
{
    void DoThings {}
}
public class SomeService : IService1, IService2
{
    public void DoStuff() {}
    public void DoThings() {}
}
```

My autofac registration would look like this

```cs
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>()
     .As<IService1>()
     .As<IService2>()
     .SingleInstance();
```

What would the equivalent of this look like in DryIoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegisterMany` or `RegisterMapping` is it. Here is the [docs](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registermany).